# C++ Vector class as a member in other class

Tags: c++, vector

Please I have this code which gives me many errors:

```
//Neuron.h File
#ifndef Neuron_h
#define Neuron_h
#include "vector"
class Neuron
{
private:
 vector<double>lstWeights;
public:
 vector<double> GetWeight();

};
#endif

//Neuron.cpp File
#include "Neuron.h"
vector<double> Neuron::GetWeight()
{
 return lstWeights;
}
```

Could any one tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: Not without error messages, usually...

Comment: Post a little more details, error messages, more code, etc

Comment: Do you mean std::vector? Do you want to return a copy of the whole verctor each time GetWeight() is called?

Comment: For the sake of the community, it would be helpful if you accepted the best answer (for this question and your others).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's:

```
#include <vector>
```

You use angle-brackets because it's part of the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), "" with just make the compiler look in other directories first, which is unnecessarily slow. And it is located in the namespace `std`:

```
std::vector<double>
```

You need to qualify your vector in the correct namespace:

```
class Neuron
{
private:
 std::vector<double>lstWeights;
public:
 std::vector<double> GetWeight();

};

std::vector<double> Neuron::GetWeight()
```

Made simpler with typedef's:

```
class Neuron
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<double> container_type;

    const container_type& GetWeight(); // return by reference to avoid
                                       // unnecessary copying

private: // most agree private should be at bottom
    container_type lstWeights;
};

const Neuron::container_type& Neuron::GetWeight()
{
 return lstWeights;
}
```

Also, don't forget to be [const-correct](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html):

```
const container_type& GetWeight() const; // const because GetWeight does
                                         // not modify the class
```

Comment: @ChrisW bad idea in general, there could be a vector class in another library.

Comment: @ChrisW I'm sure you know, but just for the author's sake, you shouldn't include all of `std::` in a header. Either just do `using std::vector` after the `#include` statement, or reference it as `std::vector<T>` every time

Comment: @GMan, using "vector" instead of <vector> will just slow down the preprocessor. Using quotes instead of angular brackets just tells the compiler to look first in the current directory, and if nothing found, look in the appropriate include dirs

Comment: Right, that's why it should be <>. Maybe I'll make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `#include <vector>`. Note the angular brackets.

Secondly, it's 'std::vector', not just 'vector' (or use 'using' directive).

Thirdly, don't return vectors by value. This is heavy and usually completely unnecessary. Return a [const] reference instead

```
class Neuron {
private: 
    std::vector<double> lstWeights;
public: 
    const vector<double>& GetWeight() const;
};    

const std::vector<double>& Neuron::GetWeight() const
{ 
  return lstWeights;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef Neuron_h
#define Neuron_h
#include "vector"

using std::vector;

class Neuron
{
private:
 vector<double>lstWeights;
public:
 vector<double> GetWeight();

};
#endif
```

try that

Comment: That still won't work, unless OP has a library named "vector" in the same directory.  He likely meant `#include <vector>`

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `vector` with `std::vector`, a la:

```
std::vector<double> lstWeights;
```

The issue is that the standard containers are in the standard namespace, so you have to somehow let the compiler know that you'd like to use the standard namespace's version of vector; you do that one of several ways, `std::vector` being the most explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing `vector<double>` with `std::`, e.g. `std::vector<double>`, should do the work.